# Extract text including line breaks from XML with PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, text

When I extract text from an XML file

```
Here is some text before the
<br/><br/>
line break.
```

in PHP,

```
echo $value->description;
```

I get the text but not the including br tags. How do I get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show some data. What does the text look like originally?

Comment: Looks like the XML file is not set up correctly. If the content of a node is supposed to be HTML, then the entire content must be enclosed in `<![CDATA[...]]>` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdata). Otherwise the content will be interpreted by the XML parser and the HTML tags will create new nodes (that is what you experience now). If you have control over the XML file, make sure you set it up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And from experience, you shouldn't even get any text after the `<br/>` tags. Reason for this is because all text nodes in XML are suppose to have < and > replaced with their htmlentity() counterparts, and all other special characters replaced with htmlspecialchars(). I'm fairly certain that it causes an error with your XML DOM parser, or at least make it as a new node, an empty text node with a line break, I think.

The only solution for this is to store the XML into a string, use regex to take out the `<br/>` tags (well, all the < and > tags for that matter), and replace them with the correct values I noted above.

Or, you can read about CDATA [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp), and escape the tags instead, but that's if you're the one creating that XML file. You should notify the webmaster for the site that you got the XML from, that the XML is incorrectly created.

Comment: Yep, it was the lack of CDATA

Answer (score 0):

First, you can read the XML file into one string, and then replace '
' by '<br/>'. Now, you can load the replaced string as XML data, and process it with XML DOM.